# Round to quarter hour; aspx.vb

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile

Working on a website that's a combination of Jquery Mobile and ASP 4.  Currently I'm stuck on a form I'm trying to get to do a SQL insert.  I'm trying to use code behind in VB to handle my insert...

All that to say: I need my page to convert a minute value into hour&quarter hour format, rounding to nearest quarter hour.

Currently I'm taking two times entered into text boxes (ex. 8:00:00 AM and 9:12:00 AM). If I use a TimeSpan I can calculate the difference between the two values and dump that difference into a variable, for example tElapsed = tSpan.TotalMinutes.ToString would set tElapsed = 72 for the above times.  I need to convert this to a 1.0hr, 1.25hr, 1.5hr, etc format and round 3+ minutes to next half hour... and I keep getting stuck.

Synopsis:

Have:

```
Text Box: Time1 = 8:00:00 AM
Text Box: Time2 = 9:12:00 AM
Dim tDiff As String = DateTime.Parse.(Time2.Text) - DateTime.Parse(Time1.Text)
Dim tElapse As String = tDiff.TotalMinutes.ToString
```

tElapse will return 72 for the above, now I need to convert 72 (minutes) to 1.25 (hours).

1.25 hours can be any of: 64 minutes - 78 minutes

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Math.DivRem

```
int remainder;
int whole = Math.DivRem(tDiff.TotalMinutes, 60, out remainder);
```

At this point remainder will now be what's left between hours. 0 to 59 minutes. I wasn't clearn on how you wanted exactly to round that, but (double)remainder / 60.00 will give you the decimal place, which you can then add to the whole.

Comment: Thank you!  That did it.  I used that and CASE to finish up, I knew case would come into play, but I couldn't figure out how to seperate the "remainder".  Below is my code:

Comment: `Dim tDff As TimeSpan = DateTime.Parse(tbEnd.Text) - DateTime.Parse(tbStrt.Text)
    Dim mins As Integer = tDff.TotalMinutes.ToString
    Dim rmndr As Integer
    Dim hrs As String = Math.DivRem(mins, 60, rmndr)
    Dim qtyordr As String
    Select Case rmndr
         Case 1 To 2
             qtyordr = hrs
         Case 3 To 18
             qtyordr = hrs & ".25"
         Case 19 To 28
             qtyordr = hrs & ".50"
         Case 29 To 48
             qtyordr = hrs & ".75"
         Case Else
             qtyordr = (hrs + 1) & ".00"
         End Select
    lblResult.Text = qtyordr`

Comment: Sorry if posting the reply's has flooded you with messages.  Last one I promise.  Just wanted to complain about it butchering the code structure...

Comment: No worries, glad you were able to put it all together!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I used, posting it as an answer so the code structure will show up:

```
    Dim tDiff As TimeSpan = DateTime.Parse(textboxEnd.Text) - DateTime.Parse(textboxStart.Text)
    Dim mins As Integer = tDiff.TotalMinutes.ToString
    Dim remainder As Integer
    Dim hrs As String = Math.DivRem(mins, 60, remainder)
    Dim qtyorder As String
    Select Case remainder
        Case 1 To 2
            qtyorder = hrs
        Case 3 To 18
            qtyorder = hrs & ".25"
        Case 19 To 28
            qtyorder = hrs & ".50"
        Case 29 To 48
            qtyorder = hrs & ".75"
        Case Else
            qtyorder = (hrs + 1) & ".00"
    End Select

    lblResult.Text = qtyorder
```